# $f(x,y)=4x^3y^2$ Dealing with Directional Derivatives and Vectors

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f(x,y)=4x^3y^2$

How do I find the directional derivative of $f$ at $(2,1)$ in the direction of the vector $3i-4j$? What would be a unit vector in the direction in which $f$ decreases most rapidly from the point $(2,1)$? And, what is the rate of change of $f$ in the direction given in the second question?

**My Work (What I have done so far):**

For the first question: $\nabla f(x,y)=12x^2y^2$**i**$+8x^3y$**j**$\nabla f(2,1)=48$**i**$+64$**j**$u=(3/5)$**i**$-(4/5)$**j** $\therefore D_u f=\nabla f\bullet u=0$

I'm not entirely sure if this is right? Can someone please verify?

For the second question: $u=(3/5)$**i**$-(4/5)$**j** $\therefore -||\nabla f(2,1)||=$? How do I find this? And am I doing this right?

I have no idea what to do for the third question.

Comment: **1**. [$(48,64).(3/5,-4/5)$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%2848%2C64%29.%283%2F5%2C-4%2F5%29) $=-\frac{112}{5}$, **2** .The direction is $-\nabla f(2,1)$ , **3**. Since one have a direction vector and the gradient, the rate of change is dot product of these two

Comment: possible duplicate of [$f(x,y)=4x^3y^2$ Directional Derivative...](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1293559/fx-y-4x3y2-directional-derivative)